# add class members at run-time

Tags: python, class, python-3.x

what is difference between this two Person's instance?

```
class Person:
    pass

a = Person()
a.name = "Jo"
a.age = 25

print(a.name)

b = Person()
b.surname = "Deshu"
print(b.surname)
```

Is `a` and `b` same type? - Yes. 
Why? They have different members
`a` have `Person.name` and `Person.age` attributes, `b` have only `Person.surname`

Comment: Why not use e.g. `type(a)` to find out?

Answer (score 3):

They are the same type.
note that in python inheritance is a bit different hen in static typed language.

python uses duck typing - that is, you don't have to have a common super class or interface to allow polymorphism - you just have to have the relevant  methods \ properties.

on the other hand, having the ability to define dynamic fields or methods makes it possible to have different objects of the same class with a different set of methods \ properties.

it's up to you not to abuse duck typing

python inheritance is more relevant for behavior inheritance - inheriting method implementation from the super class.

Answer (score 0):

As is true for modules, classes partake of the dynamic nature of Python: they are created at runtime, and can be modified further after creation.

You can check out the python documentation on the subject.
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html